# Azure custom RM role definition with special AssignableScopes

Tags: azure, powershell, rbac

I'm trying to create a custom Azure RM role definition which scope for some resource groups inside one subscription. I don’t want to provide access to all subscription or only one resource group, and I can’t specify the list of resource groups because some of them are not created yet. I want to provide access only so some subset of subscription resource groups.

For that I use PowerShell cmdlet

```
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -InputFile .\new-role.json
```

Where JSON is

```
{
  "Name": "RoleAssignmentsWriter",
  "Description": "Allow to perform role assignment",
  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write"
  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/prefix*"
  ]
}
```

Where ***prefix*** is the prefix of existed and feature resource group names.

It works if `AssignableScopes: [“/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx”]` – whole subscription or if `AssignableScopes: ["/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName”]`

But don’t work if I specify `AssignableScopes: ["/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/prefix*"]` or even `AssignableScopes: ["/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/*"]`.

One important thing is that I want to create Role Definition for not existed resource groups yet, they will be created later.

The question is: is it possible to specify `AssignableScopes` to only some subset of subscription resource groups? Maybe I can use some kind of wildcard  within `AssignableScopes`? Simple star mark doesn’t work. 
Or maybe I can use resource group tags or something else?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: i dont think it supports wildcard matches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it possible to specify AssignableScopes to only some subset of subscription resource groups? Maybe I can use some kind of wildcard within AssignableScopes?

AFAIK, you could not use wildcard within `assignableScopes`, the `New-AzureRmRoleDefinition` powershell command essentially calls the [`Role Definitions - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/createorupdate) REST API, the `assignableScopes` only accept three types, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-rest#create-a-custom-role).

[image]

If you want to  specify AssignableScopes to only some subset of subscription resource groups, you need to specific them one by one in the `assignableScopes`, like

```
 "assignableScopes": [
      "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup1",
      "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup2",
      "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup3",
    ]
```

> Or maybe I can use resource group tags or something else?

No, the possible properties are all listed in the REST API doc, there is no other ones.